# Barcode Scanner for Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, barcode, qr-code, barcode-scanner

So I'm building a Rails App for a client where they'll be receiving inbound shipments from customers. In order to streamline the process, the client would like to have a barcode system where they can just scan the incoming shipments that will automatically update statuses on a specific order within my app.

Here is my question. What I'd like to see happen is for the user to scan a barcode (using whatever hardware available) and that in turn populates an input field in my rails app. Ultimately, this would be a form and when submitted it will auto update a specific order.

Is there specific hardware that I'd need to get? Any kind of ruby gems that would be good for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your usual bar code scanner acts as a keyboard. It reads the code and sends it to the computer followed by an enter. Maybe you want mobile devices to do the scanning, which might be a bit more involved.

Comment: Hi--yes this is exactly what i want-- so are you saying that I we can get any barcode scanner and this is what that will do?

Comment: @user3310616 The ones I've had experience with did that. I'm not aware of any others. I'm not sure about the QR code scanners.

Comment: --thanks so much! I figured my question was pretty basic but yet wasnt able to understand the fundamentals--thanks so much, i'll go ahead and buy a scanner off amazon!